# Scrolling, growing, shrinking, randomly placed image marquee?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We trying to get a looping marquee effect for our 'customers' page similar to Stripe's About page. What would be the approach here? It seems like theres a couple things happening here:

- looping/infinite scrolling
- growing onload
- randomly placed but not overlapping
- random sizing
- growing/shrinking as they reach the edge of the container (couldn't find this *anywhere*)

Would it be even worth it to pursue this effect? Stripe's js file is too advanced for me to figure out. Any ideas?

Reference: https://stripe.com/about

This is what is looks like now (static, no movement, scrolling, etc.):

[image: marquee look: current]

```css
.container {max-width:1140px;margin:0 auto;}

.doc-portrait {border-radius: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 50px 49px 0px 50px;
    display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container clear">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60/007ee5/ffffff" class="doc-portrait">
</div>
```

What we wish it could look like (with scrolling, grow/shrink,etc.) (We can add as many avatars as needed to fill it up):

[image: We wish]

Really going in circles with this...

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be even worth it to pursue this effect?

No.

Most likely not. It's pretty neat, that's for sure. Do you have pictures of all of your customers? Do you have info and links for them? That's what the stripe page is about... showing they have tons of happy employees who you can click on and see their story and their github or twitter...  It's just fun, because they have money and time to do fun things.

I would suggest writing down the goal of your page, and then finding the quickest way to that goal. I'm betting it's not going to be copying this avatar slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stream-of-consciousness take on it.

I would have an array that kept track of which avatars were currently on screen, and which ones were not, moving items between them as they appear/ disappear.

When you move one onscreen, it goes to the far right with size zero, and a random radius and y-position. Before placing it, use some geometry (maybe there's a method to do this?) to see if it intersects with any other circles (you can get their positions using a method below). If a height doesn't work, keep trying until you find one that does. A simple animation class runs once to grow the element.

There is a method, getBoundingClientRect(), which gives element positions in viewport coordinates. You can attach an event listener to each avatar to see if the value of left returned by getBoundingClientRect is less than wherever you want to start shrinking, then use a simple css shrinking animation.